Computing all the Galois groups of reducible polynomials of degree 5 over $\mathbb{Q}$
in my Algebra class, it was given as an exercise to find all possible Galois groups of reducible polynomials of degree 5 over $\mathbb{Q}$ without repeated roots.
Where, for a field $F$, we call the Galois group of a polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ the Galois group of one of its splitting extensions $E/F$.
Now, I've already classified all possible Galois groups of irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree 1 (the trivial group $\{1\}$), 2 ($S_2$), 3 ($A_3$ and $S_3$) and 4 ($V_4$, $C_4$, $D_4$, $A_4$ and $S_4$). My idea is to recover the Galois group of a reducible $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree 5 without repeated roots starting from these groups as follows.
Every map in the Galois group $G$ of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ can only shuffle separately the roots of the irreducible factors of $f(x)$. So, say that $f(x)=g_1(x)\cdot\ldots\cdot g_k(x)$ is a decomposition in irreducible factors in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, $G\leq G_1\times\ldots\times G_k$, with $G_i$ Galois group of $f_i(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. We distinguish then the cases:
i- $deg(g_i)=1$ for all $i\leq k=5$, then $G=\{1\}$;
ii- $deg(g_1)=2$ and $deg(g_i)=1$ for all $i\neq 1$, then $G=G_1=S_2$;
iii- $deg(g_1)=3$ and $deg(g_i)=1$ for all $i\neq 1$, then $G=G_1$, which can be only $A_3$ or $S_3$;
iv- $deg(g_1)=4$ and $deg(g_i)=1$ for all $i\neq 1$, then $G=G_1$, which as before can be only $V_4$, $C_4$, $D_4$, $A_4$ or $S_4$;
v- $deg(g_1)=deg(g_2)=2$ and the remaining factor of order 1, then we consider the splitting field $E_j\subseteq\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ of $g_j(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, for $j\leq k$. The intersection $E_1\cap E_2$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector subspace of $E_1$ and $E_2$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$, so it has at least dimension 1. If $dim(E_1\cap E_2)=1$, then $E_1\cap E_2=\mathbb{Q}$ and then $G=G_1\times G_2=S_2\times S_2$. Conversely, if $dim(E_1\cap E_2)=2$, then $E_1=E_2$ and $G=G_1=G_2=S_2$. These seem to be the only possibilities according to Linear Algebra;
vi- $deg(g_1)=3$, $deg(g_2)=2$ and $k=2$. Then, arguing as above, $E_1\cap E_2$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector subspace of $E_1$ and $E_2$ of dimension at least 1 and can only have:
(a)- $dim(E_1\cap E_2)=1$, then $E_1\cap E_2=\mathbb{Q}$ and then $G=G_1\times G_2=G_1\times S_2$, with $G_1\in \{A_3, S_3\}$;
(b)- $dim(E_1\cap E_2)=2$, then $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq E_1\cap E_2=E_2\subseteq E_1$. From here by using the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory we can get that $Gal(E_1/E_2)$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1$ of index $|G_2|=|S_2|=2$. However, except for this, I don't see how to settle this last case, is there anything I'm missing?
Moreover, is the argument above correct? Also, do you know any examples of polynomials for the cases v and vi-(a)?
I would appreciate any help, thanks.

It's not clear to me, what do you think is missing from (vi-b)? When $Gal(E_1/\Bbb{Q})$ has an index two subgroup, it has to be all of $S_3$. This happens for example, when
$$f(x)=(x^3-2)(x^2+3).$$ Anyway, looks like you have all the cases.

Well, the goal is to compute $G$ also in this case. My argument above is incomplete since it does not provide $G$

As $E_2\subseteq E_1$, you see that $E_1$ is the splitting field of $f$. So the Galois group is $G=S_3$.

Correct. Well done! Feel free to relocate that comment into an answer box. That way you can mark this question as answered, and also get feedback from others.

Done, thank you again! I've just also edited the question because I'd like to see some examples of such polynomials for the cases (v) and (vi)-(a). I'll close the post as soon as I'll get them

I'm just resuming here @JyrkiLahtonen nice suggestion.
Since we have that $f(x)=g_1(x)\cdot g_2(x) \cdot (x-\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}$, $E_i$ is the splitting field of $g_i(x)$, for $i=1,2$ (i.e. the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ obtained by adding just the roots of $g_i(x)$) and $E_2\subseteq E_1$, we have that $E_1$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence, $G=G_1$, which can only be $S_3$ since this is the only subgroup of $S_3$ having a proper subgroup of index 2.
